# Folders are not listed in Eclipse's Project view - preventing marking a folder as "source folder"

Tags: eclipse

I have messed up my Eclipse project and am trying to create a new workspace and re-importing everything but that is more complicated than one would expect.

Currently the problem is that Eclipse doesn't recognize in what folders the source files are stored. Usually you can right click on a folder and mark it as a source folder:

[image]

But in my new workspace, no folders are displayed, only packages, and it looks the same in Package explorer and Project explorer:

[image: Folders are missing in Package explorer]

[image: Folders are missing in Project explorer]

As you can see `src` is in the "path" but visually it is not a folder on a separate level in the hierarchy.

---

If I create another workspace and add a couple of projects it looks right:
[image: How it should look]

---

**Why are my folders missing? How do I make Eclipse show them and/or select them as source folders?**

Answer (score 0):

`src` is inside of a folder that is already set as a source folder. You'll have to unset the parent folder as a Source folder before you can set `src` to be one.